# Какое здесь средство выразительности?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Будущее готовит тебе гибель? Метафора или метонимия?

Comment: метонимия скорее ~ в будущем тебе кто-то готовит гибель, в будущем тебя ждет гибель.

Comment: @Буратино Уточнила у "Грамоты". Сказали, что метафора. Спасибо

Comment: Вопрос снимаю. Ответ получила от филологов.

Comment: Не является ответом. Напишите, пожалуйста,  ответ филологов. Другой вариант: Если вопрос неактуален для вас, то его можно удалить.

Comment: ... Чаще всего классификация метонимий сводится к трем главным группам: или в основание деления кладутся отношения пространственные, временные и причинные, или же категории сосуществования, последовательности и логической внутренней связи...Так, категории пространственная и временная в известных случаях объединяются категорией сосуществования (наприм., именование места в смысле его населения — «Украина глухо волновалась», — и именование периода времени в смысле явлений, которые происходили в его течение — «голодный год», «бронзовый век»).

Comment: М. Петровский. Литературная энциклопедия: Словарь литературных терминов: В 2-х т. / Под редакцией Н. Бродского, А. Лаврецкого, Э. Лунина, В. Львова-Рогачевского, М. Розанова, В. Чешихина-Ветринского. — М.; Л.: Изд-во Л. Д. Френкель, 1925

Comment: Но как скажете.